# Qt drawLine with width 1

Tags: qt, graphics

I am writing a CAD program and I found a strange bug, to cut the long story short, the following code shows the bug:

```
p.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 3));
p.drawLine(410.738, 364.399, -63151.2, -63197.6);
p.setPen(QPen(Qt::cyan, 1));
p.drawLine(410.738, 364.399, -63151.2, -63197.6);
```

[image]

although start and end coordinates are exactly the same, these two lines slopes are different (first line has the correct slope while cyan line is incorrect). is there any suggestion?

P.S: I use Qt 4.72

Comment: Please link some screenshot.

Comment: Did you read documentation about `QPen`? This - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#PenCapStyle-enum. Do you know what is anti-aliasing?

Comment: Yes I do. The slopes are very different. It has nothing to do with Anitialiasing. Here is a screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B27B8z6nB60aNFZxQktMTE1Xdnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are everything OK on your screenshot. It works as expected. Try to use `Qt::FlatCap`

Comment: No it is not! the slope of "cyan" line and "white" is different. but It shouldn't be. that is the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use wrong `drawLine()` signature. The one you use takes `int` as argument. The `double` values get converted to `int`. Depending on the architecture, the resulting value may be too big to be converted to `int` and you get an undefined behavior. Use `drawLine()` in conjunction with `QPointF`:

```
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::white, 3));
    p.drawLine(QPointF(410.738, 364.399), QPointF(-63151.2, -63197.6));
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::cyan, 1));
    p.drawLine(QPointF(410.738, 364.399), QPointF(-63151.2, -63197.6));
```

[image]